# Saving an excel file using pandas in a specific file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I would like a excel file to be stored in a .xlsx format into a specific folder that i called data. The file is in the same folder as the programm running.

The programm create a new `mydict` every hour that's why I have it in the name so I can work on it later on.

```
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas import ExcelWriter
    import datetime

    mydict = self._detailed_cost
    todays_date = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H%M"))

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict, orient='index')
    with ExcelWriter('data/' + todays_date + '-cost_function'+'.xlsx') as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, 'costs', index=True)
```

Running this code i get the following error:

```
OSError: Cannot save file into a non-existent directory: '..\data'
```

Idealy i would'nt give an absolute path since I'm coding on one PC and I'd like it to run on an other one with a different path.

Answer (score 0):

```
 with ExcelWriter(r'data/' + todays_date + '-cost_function'+'.xlsx') as writer:
```

As the above use `r` at the start of the path to indicate that a relative path.